# Add special character folding to list filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use list.js to live filter a list.
http://www.listjs.com/examples

But I need to add folding. If someone types in 'á' it should find also list items with 'a'.

Any ideas?

I could add a hidden span to ever list item without special chars and then a hidden input that contains the same string the user inputs but without special chars and use those for the list.js but that dies not seem very good...

Or maybe any similar plugins with this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with this library, but this might work (this is using code from the example you linked to):

```
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
  plugins: (function() {
      options = options || {};
      return {
        init: function(list) {
          // This method is called on initialization
          events.bind(getByClass(list.listContainer, options.searchClass), 'keyup', function(e) {
                    var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // IE have srcElement
                    list.search(target.value);
                });
        },
        name: options.name || "newsearch",
        search: function(str, columns) {
          var combining = /[\u0300-\u036F]/g; 
          var new_str = str.normalize('NFKD').replace(combining, '');
          list.search(new_str, columns);

        }
      };
    })()
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but did not work :( I tested your idea here: http://curves-academia.com/test.php